# random.choice not working when selecting from a dictionary value which is a list

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I'm making a program to randomly make a god with influence over a thing, and influence over things related to the original. The relevant parts are:

```
spheres = {'death': ['death', 'corpses', 'skulls', 'rot', 'ruin', 'the end']}
# Dictionary of the things gods have power over and the relevant things to do with them

class God(object):

  def __init__(self, sphere, associations, name):
    self.sphere = sphere
    self.associations = accociations
    self.name = name
# Chooses areas to have power over, hopefully making it less and less likely as the program goes on further      
  def get_association(self):
    chance_of_association = 0
    list_of_choices = []
    while random.randint(0, chance_of_association) == 0:
      choice = random.choice(list(spheres[self.sphere]))
      # this is the problem
      if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
        chance_of_association += 1
      list_of_choices.append(choice)
    self.associations = list_of_choices

deity1 = God(random.choice(spheres), deity1.get_association, 'godname')
```

When I run this, I get:

```
  File "program.py", line 22, in <module>
    deity1 = God(random.choice(spheres), deity1.get_association, 'godname')
  File "/opt/python-3.6/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 258, in choice
    return seq[i]
KeyError: 0
```

Even without the list() in the line it produces the same error. How can I get it

Comment: Do you mean `random.choice(spheres['death'])`?

Comment: If not, please explain what you're trying to do. (You're passing a `dict` to `random.choice`, which doesn't really make sense.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

spheres = {'death': ['death', 'corpses', 'skulls', 'rot', 'ruin', 'the end']}
# Dictionary of the things gods have power over and the relevant things to do with them

class God(object):

  def __init__(self, sphere, name, associations = None):
    self.sphere = sphere
    #so associations are not allocated twice
    self.possible_associations = spheres[self.sphere] 
    self.associations = associations
    self.get_association()
    self.name = name
# Chooses areas to have power over, hopefully making it 
# less and less likely as the program goes on further      
  def get_association(self):
    chance_of_association = 0
    list_of_choices = []
    while random.randint(0, chance_of_association) == 0 and self.possible_associations:
      choice = random.choice(self.possible_associations)
      self.possible_associations.remove(choice)
      if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
        chance_of_association += 1
      list_of_choices.append(choice)
    self.associations = list_of_choices
```

You cannot reference 'diety1', and call it's method, 'get_association', during instantiation because the object has not yet been created.  So we moved the method call to happen when `__init__` runs. And we had to change random.choice to search through the list of keys in the dictionary.

```
deity1 = God(random.choice(list(spheres.keys())), 'godname')
```

Comment: Thank you, this explanation made sense

Answer (score 2):

You can change the line as

```
deity1 = God(random.choice(spheres['death']), deity1.get_association, 'godname')
```

But this also makes another error, so please have a look on your code again.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 23, in <module>
NameError: name 'deity1' is not defined
```